# How to merge two trees in Haskell

Tags: haskell, binary-tree

Assuming I am using a tree structured using the following:

```
data Tree a = LEAF a | NODE a (Tree a) (Tree a) 
              deriving (Show, Read, Eq)
```

How would I go about creating a function capable of adding together the values found at each equivalent node/leaf w/out importing any libraries (leaving me with the Prelude library), and is compatible with

```
function :: Num a => Tree a -> Tree a -> Tree a
```

As an example, assume the input is

```
left = NODE 1 (NODE 2 (NODE 3 (LEAF 4) (LEAF 5)) (LEAF 6)) (NODE 7 (LEAF 8) (LEAF 9)) 
 
right = NODE 1 (NODE 2 (LEAF 3) (LEAF 6)) (NODE 7 (NODE 8 (LEAF 10) (LEAF 11)) (LEAF 9)) 

merge_trees left right
```

Then the output should be

```
NODE 2  
(NODE 4 (NODE 6 (LEAF 4) (LEAF 5)) (LEAF 12))  
(NODE 14 (NODE 16 (LEAF 10) (LEAF 11)) (LEAF 18))
```

Any and all help would be appreciated.

Comment: A simpler example would help; currently I'm wondering where did `1` go from both trees?

Comment: And where did the second `4` come from?

Comment: @Koterpillar I apologize, I explained the problem very poorly - it adds the values found at each equivalent node/leaf together, so the 1s merged to become that 2. This should help

https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/936886164101677076/946666033203281930/unknown.png

Comment: @jlwoodwa See the above comment

Comment: What happens if the two trees are not identically shaped?

Comment: @Chris Any remaining nodes/leafs are added without being modified. As seen in the image with the 4 and 5, as well as the 10 and 11.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is really quite straightforward if we think through the different combinations of arguments to `merge_trees`.

- A leaf and another leaf.
- A leaf on the left and a node on the right.
- A node on the left and a leaf on the right.
- A node on the left and a node on the right.

The first case is *very* simple.

```
merge_trees (LEAF a) (LEAF b) = LEAF (a + b)
```

The second and third cases only require us to add the value of the leaf to the value of the node, and return the rest of the node unchanged.

```
merge_trees (LEAF a) (NODE b l r) = NODE (a + b) l r
merge_trees (NODE b l r) (LEAF a) = NODE (a + b) l r
```

The last option takes the most work but is fundamentally straightforward. We add the values of both nodes, and construct a new node with that value and the results of recursively applying `merge_trees` to the corresponding branches of both nodes.

```
merge_trees (NODE a l r) (NODE b l' r') = NODE v l'' r''
  where 
    v = a + b
    l'' = merge_trees l l'
    r'' = merge_trees r r'
```

```
Prelude> left = NODE 1 (NODE 2 (NODE 3 (LEAF 4) (LEAF 5)) (LEAF 6)) (NODE 7 (LEAF 8) (LEAF 9))
Prelude> right = NODE 1 (NODE 2 (LEAF 3) (LEAF 6)) (NODE 7 (NODE 8 (LEAF 10) (LEAF 11)) (LEAF 9))
Prelude> merge_trees left right
NODE 2 (NODE 4 (NODE 6 (LEAF 4) (LEAF 5)) (LEAF 12)) (NODE 14 (NODE 16 (LEAF 10) (LEAF 11)) (LEAF 18))
```